# How to automatically assign input?

Tags: python

I'm asked to create a script to calculate grade average, however I don't know how to do this.

> Your script should be able to process any number of exam scores. If the user specifies the class size to be n, then your script should prompt for exactly n exam scores.

It should show this

```
What is the size of the class?  5
Now enter the scores below.
Student 1: 79
Student 2: 87
Student 3: 67
Student 4: 96
Student 5: 83
The average is 82.4.
```

This script works but it's not clean and doesn't go pass the alphabet. And is leading to trouble in the actual averaging part.

```
class_size = input('What is the class size: ')
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
student = {}

def size_class(class_size):
    while class_size != 0:
        assign = alphabet[class_size]
        student[assign] = input('Student: ')
        class_size = class_size - 1

size_class(class_size)

print student['b'] + 1
```

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate an average?

Comment: No just this particular calculate an average, which is input the user wanted amount of students.

Comment: That sentence didn't make much sense. I'm not trying to be rude, I'm trying to understand the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not trying get the whole entire script answered that's why I just have part of the question.

Comment: Sorry user334912 your question is not horrible I voted it up because you have work here and I think there are plenty of super programmers who dislike having novices ask easy questions or confusing questions. I hope the vote downs don't keep you from coming back and asking more questions.  It took me awhile to learn how to ask question but it was worth.  Again I personally do not think there is anything substantive wrong with yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list is probably a better structure here than a dictionary:

```
scores = []
for n in range(class_size):
    scores.append(int(raw_input("Student {0}: ".format(n+1))))
average = sum(scores) / float(len(scores))
```

I am not sure why you are trying to use the alphabet, but it will limit you to 26 students.

Comment: Thank you, there are alot of things in here I don't know about. That's why I was improvising with the alphabet assignment

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
def size_class(class_size):
    grades = []
    for num in range(class_size):
        grades.append(raw_input('Student %d:' % num)
    return grades
```